# Package Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part

How do I package a content query web part in a custom solution with its custom XSL? Do I need to store the xsl in style library's xsl style sheets folder?

I just want to have a content query web part with its custom xsl, and be able to package it in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can make the customization then export the WebPart. This gives you a file with `.webpart` extension.

Now create a new SharePoint project in Visual Studio. Add a Visual WebPart. This creates a `.webpart` file. Replace this file with the one you have exported.

Now you can make the necessary changes, then package and deploy the solution.

Comment: And how do I connect it to XSL? Do I have to have a template in the style library xsl style sheets or can I just make an .xsl file? Also how do I deploy this template, just in a module? Do you have a walkthrough for that?

Comment: I would suggest you directly put the xsl modification in the webpart file. That way you can avoid another file maintenance.

Comment: But what if I have to change later the styles? Do you have a guidance for that?

Comment: If you are changing it often the deploy the XSL file using a module.

Comment: Thanks Amal, but do you have a guidance for these processes I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps for preparation:

1. Create the custom style sheet. Upload the style sheet Style Library.
2. Add Content Query Web Part to a Page and then export it.
3. Update the style related properties. Save the web part file and upload it back to SharePoint and then add it to a page and verify that your customizations are working.

Packaging in Visual Studio.

1. Add a WebPart to the VS solution. It creates a .webpart file.
2. Replace the contents of above .webpart file with the contents of .webpart file created during step 3 of preparation.
3. Now add a module to the solution and replace the automatically generated .txt file with the style sheet file created in step 1 of preparation.
4. Update the Elements.xml file of module so that style sheet is deployed to Style Library. Example

> ```
> <Module Name="Styles" Url="style Library">
> <File Path="Styles\newstyle.css" Url="newstyle.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
> </Module>
> ```

Useful references: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/09/cqwp-xsl-customizations.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2009/11/23/how-to-deploy-a-style-sheet-into-content-library-using-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx

Comment: Hi Nadeem, thanks for your answer, I tried packaging the CQWP by exporting it and adding it to my visual studio project, after deploying the web part on a page, it told me there are some errors in the web part, until I opened the properties and just clicked Ok again, the error is gone. No correlation ID or anything.

Comment: hmm, not sure what can be the reason.